# Show the sum of data values on top of stacked bar chart using Baidu ECharts

Tags: javascript, echarts, baidu

I've created a vertical [stacked bar chart](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-bar.stack) with [Baidu ECharts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html).

Is it possible to show the *sum* of all values on top of the stack?

Edited :
i have edited my example using the (very well explained) answer from @jeffrey but i get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined** error. What am i doing wrong here ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
       <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="echarts-en.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
var     mySeries = [
            {
                name: 'Department 1',
                type: 'bar',
                stack: 'stack1',
                data: [320, 302, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
            },
            {
                name: 'Department 2',
                type: 'bar',
                stack: 'stack1',
                data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
            },
            {
                name: 'Department 3',
                type: 'bar',
                stack: 'stack1',
                data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
            },
            {
                name: 'Department 4',
                type: 'bar',
                stack: 'stack1',
                data: [150, 212, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
            },
            {
                name: 'Department 5',
                type: 'bar',
                stack: 'stack1',
                data: [185, 120, 55, 66, 77, 88, 40],
                label: {
                            normal: {
                                show: true,
                                position: 'top',
                                formatter: (params) => {
                                    let total = 0;
                                    this.series.forEach(serie => {
                                       total += serie.data[params.dataIndex];
                                    })
                                    return total;
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
        ];

        var dom = document.getElementById("container");
        var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
        var option = null;

        option = {
            tooltip : {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer : {        
                    type : 'shadow'       
                }
            },
            legend: {
                data: ['Department 1', 'Department 2','Department 3','Department 4','Department 5'],
            },
            toolbox: {
                show: true,
                orient: 'vertical',
                left: 'right',
                top: 'center',
                feature: {
                    dataView: {show: false, readOnly: false},
                    magicType: {show: true, type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack', 'tiled']},
                    restore: {show: true},
                    saveAsImage: {show: true}
                }
            },
            grid: {
                left: '3%',
                right: '4%',
                bottom: '3%',
                containLabel: true
            },
            yAxis:  {
                type: 'value'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                data: ["Jen\n2018", "Feb\n2018", "Mar\n2018", "Apr\n2018", "May\n2018", "Jun\n2018", "Jul\n2018"]
            }
        };;

        myChart.setOption(option, true);

        myChart.setOption({
            series: mySeries
        })
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You get an error because you've created `var mySeries`, but in the formatter, you reference it with `this.mySeries`, therefore it's `undefined`.

Comment: @Jeffrey : It doesn't work even if i define it as `this.mySeries`. i've made a jsfiddle to test it here : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fkossyvas/xmsyLa5c/1/)

Comment: I checked, and I made a mistake (sorry!). The forEach should've been `this.mySeries.forEach()`. [Now your fiddle works](https://jsfiddle.net/rphsn58c/) :)

Comment: Yes!  Thank you @Jeffrey for the solution! I am sorry thought i cannot mark this solution as OK since i have less of 15 reputation :-(

Comment: You're welcome! Ah, that explains why new users often not mark an answer as accepted! Maybe you can +1 for now, and mark as accepted later :)

Comment: @fkossyvas There is no reputation threshold to accept an answer.  You need to wait 15 *minutes* after asking, but that's it. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/141629)

Answer (score 8):

To get a custom [serie label](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-bar.label) you should use the [label formatter](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-bar.label.formatter).

When you define your series data *outside* of your chart object, and map it to `this`, you can access the data in the formatter. It is important to use the formatter, so the original label and values will not be altered (such as tooltips and legends).

---

First, we define your series. The formatter should be added to the *last* serie. This will be the serie on top of the stack, showing the label with the total value:

```
this.mySeries = [
    {
        name:'Dataset 1',
        type:'bar',
        stack: 'Stack 1',
        data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
        name:'Dataset 2',
        type:'bar',
        stack: 'Stack 1',
        data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
        name:'Dataset 3',
        type:'bar',
        stack: 'Stack 1',
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'top',
                formatter: (params) => {
                    let total = 0;
                    this.mySeries.forEach(serie => {
                       total += serie.data[params.dataIndex];
                    })
                    return total;
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

---

Here is the formatter again with annotations, so you can understand how this works:

```
label: {

    // You can choose from 'normal' (always visible )
    // and 'emphasis' (only visible on stack hover)
    normal: {

        // Enable the label
        show: true,

        // Position it on top of the stack
        position: 'top',

        // Add a label formatter
        // (params) holds all the data of the current serie and datapoint
        // You can use console.log(params) to check all available values
        formatter: (params) => {
            let total = 0;

            // Now we iterate over each of the series, and get the value of
            // the current xAxis datapoint by using the serie dataIndex
            this.mySeries.forEach(serie => {
               total += serie.data[params.dataIndex];
            })

            // The return value will be shown on top of your stack
            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now, all you have to do is map the series data to your chart object:

```
myChart.setOption({
    series: this.mySeries
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 labels on one series? On this same example having labels on center of the series and on the third dataset; having one on center and another one on top

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer, it helped me a lot, and I did a little simplification in the code, nothing relevant. I found the explanation easier. Basically you will use the **formatter** attribute inside the label, with some specifications

serie example

```
let series = [
{
    name: 'Reclamação',
    data: this.relatos_tipo_y.R,
},
{
    name: 'Elogio',
    data: this.relatos_tipo_y.E,
},
{
    name: 'Sugestão',
    data: this.relatos_tipo_y.S,
},
{
    name: 'Denúncia',
    data: this.relatos_tipo_y.D,
},
```

];

function for formatter

```
genFormatter = (series) => {
return (param) => {
    console.log(param);
    let sum = 0;
    series.forEach(item => {
        sum += item.data[param.dataIndex];
    });
    return sum
}
```

};

inside your chart options place this

```
series: series.map((item, index) => Object.assign(item, {
     type: 'bar',
     stack: true,
     label: {
         show: index === series.length - 1,
         formatter: genFormatter(series),
         fontSize: 20,
         color: 'black',
         position: 'top'
     },
})),
```

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595793/how-to-display-sum-stack-bar-in-echarts)

**It's very similar to the other answer, but I find it easier to understand the code.**