# How to show total and % in stacked bar chart in ECharts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using ECharts stacked bar chart in [fava-dashboard](https://github.com/andreasgerstmayr/fava-dashboards) plugin. I have the following code which generates a stacked bar chart:

```
      const currencyFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: ledger.ccy,
        maximumFractionDigits: 0,
      });
      const years = helpers.iterateYears(ledger.dateFirst, ledger.dateLast);
      
      const amounts = {};
      for (let query of panel.queries) {
        amounts[query.name] = {};
        for (let row of query.result) {
          amounts[query.name][row.year] = -row.value[ledger.ccy];
        }
      }

      return {
        tooltip: {
          valueFormatter: currencyFormat.format,
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'category',
          data: years,
          axisTick: {
            alignWithLabel: true
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          axisLabel: {
            formatter: currencyFormat.format,
          },
        },
        series: panel.queries.map((query) => ({
          type: 'bar',
          barWidth: '30%',
          name: query.name,
          stack: query.stack,
          data: years.map((year) => amounts[query.name][year] ?? 0),
        })),
        onClick: (event) => {
          const query = panel.queries.find((q) => q.name === event.seriesName);
          if (query) {
            const link = query.link.replaceAll("#", "%23").replace("{year}", event.name);
            window.open(link);
          }
        },
      };
```

The chart looks OK, but I would like to make two improvements:

- At the top of the bar, I want to show the sum of all the stacks for each bar column.
- When I hover over a stack of a bar, it currently shows me the amount value for that stack. I would also like to add the % of total.

For example, if a stack has A,B,C components with values 100,200,300, I want to show total of 600 at the top and for each component I hover on, I would like to show 100 (16.67%), 200 (33.33%) and 300 (50%).

Looking at the Echart docs, I see that you have to supply some custom formatter, but I'm not sure how to proceed further. Any help will be good.

Answer (score 0):

1. I was able to solve showing the sum by using the answer in [Show the sum of data values on top of stacked bar chart using Baidu ECharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114475/show-the-sum-of-data-values-on-top-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-baidu-echarts)
2. To show the percentage, this works:

   ```
   tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
      formatter: function (params) {
          let total = 0;
          params.forEach(item => { total += item.value; });
          var res = `<div>${params[0].name}</div>`;
          params.forEach(item => {
              res += `<div>
                        <span style="display:inline-block;border-radius:10px;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:${item.color};"></span>
                        <span>${item.seriesName}</span>
                        <span style="float:right;margin-left:20px;font-weight:600">${currencyFormat.format(item.value)} (${percentFormat.format(item.value / total)})</span>
                      </div>`;
              });
          return res;
      },
      valueFormatter: currencyFormat.format,
    },
   ```